# Why is c outputting without any decimals in the command line?

Tags: c++

```
   #include<iostream>
   #include<iomanip>
   #include<cmath>
   using namespace std;

int hypotenuse(double x, double y)
{
double z;
z = sqrt(x * x + y * y);
```

this should equate to square root of 81 + 225

```
return z;
}

int main()

{
double a, b, c;
cout << "Enter the lengths of the two legs of a right triangle: ";
```

example 9 and 15

```
cin >> a >> b;
cout << endl;

c = hypotenuse(a, b);

cout << "Perimeter = " << c;
```

output should be 17.492855 but I am getting just 17

```
cout << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

[The code outputting 17 without any decimals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDkDW.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your function is returning `int` not `double` that is why you are getting just 17. Here

```
 int hypotenuse(double x, double y)
```

Change it to:

```
 double hypotenuse(double x, double y)
```

Comment: Thankyou, I just learned this in class today and it appears my memory isn't the kindest :)